# Is it possible to exclude search bots (like Google) from Cloudflare worker redirect script?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, googlebot, cloudflare-workers

I use a Cloudflare worker to redirect visitors to the correct website version like this:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
  })

  /**
   * Respond to the request
   * @param {Request} request
   */
  async function handleRequest(request) {
    country_code = request.headers.get('CF-IPCountry');
    var link;

  switch(request.headers.get('CF-IPCountry')) {
    case 'TW':  // Taiwan
    link = "https://www.website.com/twn";
        break;
    case 'TH':  // Thailand
    link = "https://www.website.com/tha";
        break;
    case 'GB':  // United Kingdom
    link = "https://www.website.com/gbr";
        break;
    case 'US':  // United States
    link = "https://www.website.com/us";
        break;
    default:
      link = "https://www.website.com/rotw" // Rest of the world
  }

  return new Response('', {
          status: 301,
          headers: {
            'Location': link
          }
        })
  }
```

The problem is that the Google bot gets redirected to website.com/us and thus my Google entry points incoming visitors straight to the /us website. Is there a way to exclude search bots from the country redirect script and route them straight to website.com instead of website.com/countrycode?

Comment: Take a look at [robots.txt](https://www.robotstxt.org/).

Comment: The robots.txt is generated dynamically by the php software that is running on the server. Changing it is currently out of my scope (sadly).

Comment: Can't you save the worker in a directory robots.txt "protects"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you do something like this. I haven't tested this.

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
  })

  /**
   * Respond to the request
   * @param {Request} request
   */
  async function handleRequest(request) {
    country_code = request.headers.get('CF-IPCountry');
    var link;

  let userAgent = request.headers.get('User-Agent') || ''
  if (userAgent.includes('Googlebot')) {
    return new Response('', {
          status: 301,
          headers: {
            'Location': "https://www.website.com/"
          }
        })
  }

  switch(request.headers.get('CF-IPCountry')) {
    case 'TW':  // Taiwan
    link = "https://www.website.com/twn";
        break;
    case 'TH':  // Thailand
    link = "https://www.website.com/tha";
        break;
    case 'GB':  // United Kingdom
    link = "https://www.website.com/gbr";
        break;
    case 'US':  // United States
    link = "https://www.website.com/us";
        break;
    default:
      link = "https://www.website.com/rotw" // Rest of the world
  }

  return new Response('', {
          status: 301,
          headers: {
            'Location': link
          }
        })
  }
```

Comment: Looking good! What is the  || '' after let userAgent = request.headers.get('User-Agent') for?

Comment: Glad to help. || is just a shorthand way of checking for null. if request.headers.get('User-Agent') resolves to null then it will fill it with an empty string instead. Stops it erroring on the second line.